# Combine multiple form array into 1 array

Tags: php, arrays

```
  ["trnx_date"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-01-10"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2017-01-10"
  }
  ["curr_from"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "USD"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "PHP"
  }
  ["curr_from_amt"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "4,000.00"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "3,000.00"
  }
  ["curr_to"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "GBP"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "SAR"
  }
  ["curr_to_amt"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "3,000.00"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "2,000.00"
  }
  ["amount"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "7,000.00"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "5,000.00"
  }
```

I have the above array which was being submitted. This input was in sets of multiple field which was generated by dynamic table row. How can I group this into 1 (one) array so that I could save in the database? Like this:

```
[cust_row] => array(
  'tranx_date' => "2017-01-10",
  'curr_from' => "USD",
  'curr_from_amt' => "4,000.00",
  'curr_to' => "GBP",
  'curr_to_amt' => "3,000.00",
  'amount' => "7,000.00"
),
[cust_row] => array(
  'tranx_date' => "2017-01-10",
  'curr_from' => "PHP",
  'curr_from_amt' => "3,000.00",
  'curr_to' => "SAR",
  'curr_to_amt' => "2,000.00",
  'amount' => "5,000.00"
),
```

All of the above we being populated like this:

```
$trnx_date = $this->input->post('trnx_date');
$curr_from = $this->input->post('curr_from');
$curr_from_amt = $this->input->post('curr_from_amt');
$curr_to = $this->input->post('curr_to');
$curr_to_amt = $this->input->post('curr_to_amt');
$amount = $this->input->post('amount');
```

Comment: Have you tried something by yourself?

Comment: I don't understand the desired row. Why isn't there a key for the second array?

Comment: Hi Perumal, sorry my bad. it supposed to have the same key for the second array..

Comment: <pre>[cust_row] => array(
  'tranx_date' => "2017-01-10",
  'curr_from' => "USD",
  'curr_from_amt' => "4,000.00",
  'curr_to' => "GBP",
  'curr_to_amt' => "3,000.00",
  'amount' => "7,000.00"
),
[cust_row] => array(
  'tranx_date' => "2017-01-10",
  'curr_from' => "PHP",
  'curr_from_amt' => "3,000.00",
  'curr_to' => "SAR",
  'curr_to_amt' => "2,000.00",
  'amount' => "5,000.00"
),
</pre>

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same key.

Comment: I'm just going to assume that the result should just be a numerically indexed array, like the sub-arrays in the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    'trnx_date' => array('2017-01-10', '2017-01-10'),
    'curr_from' => array('USD', 'PHP'),
    'curr_from_amt' => array('4,000.00', '3,000.00'),
    'curr_to' => array('GBP', 'SAR'),
    'curr_to_amt' => array('3,000.00', '2,000.00'),
    'amount' => array('7,000.00', '5,000.00')
);

$arr_out = array();
$arr_keys = array_keys($arr);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr[$arr_keys[0]]); $i++) {
    $new_arr = array();
    foreach($arr_keys as $key => $value) {
        $new_arr[$value] = $arr[$value][$i];
    }
    $arr_out[] = $new_arr;
}

var_dump($arr_out);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're my savior, this what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the sub-arrays have the same length, you can use a simple `for` loop that iterates over the index of one of them, and use that to access each of the sub-arrays at that index. Then combine all of them into the associative array for each customer.

```
$result = array();
$keys = array_keys($array);
$len = count($array[$keys[0]]); // Get the length of one of the sub-arrays
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $new = array();
    foreach ($keys as $k) {
        $new[$k] = $array[$k][$i];
    }
    $result[] = $new;
}
```

Comment: Hi Barmar,

The fields are like this:

trnx_date = $this->input->post('trnx_date');
$curr_from = $this->input->post('curr_from');
$curr_from_amt = $this->input->post('curr_from_amt');
$curr_to = $this->input->post('curr_to');
$curr_to_amt = $this->input->post('curr_to_amt');
$amount = $this->input->post('amount');

all above are being populated from a form submission

Comment: The question looks like all the inputs are in an associative array, not separate variables.

Comment: Looks like you are using CodeIgniter . The nature of the arrays you are returning will depend on how the form is constructed, so one can't say from this detail you've just provided whether Barmar's assumption is a reasonable one. If you have control over the form, you might consider changing the input names to define a more convenient array structure. E.g, <input name="[0][trnx_date]">

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
// assume $arr is your original data array
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$result = array();
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $vals = $arr[$key];
    foreach($vals as $i =>$val) {
        if (!is_array($result[$i]) {
            $result[$i] = array();
        }
        $result[$i][$key] = $val;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

EDIT: added array check for $result[$i]